# Where do I find my 26 character CD key?

Tags: diablo-ii

I recently opened my dusty box of old games and was excited to find my original CD keys for Diablo II and Diablo II Lord of Destruction.  A helpful person on this site pointed out that I could enter my keys on battle.net and download a modern version of the game compatible with my OS.  I did that, but now when the installer asks me for my CD key it mentions a 26 character key, and the key on my CD case is not nearly that long.  I'm looking at the case and it's clearly a 16 digit sequence.  Do I pad that with zeros, or is there somewhere else I can find the key I need?

Comment: Make sure you have registered the game to you battle.net account in order to convert your 16 digit key to a 26 digit key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can log in to battle net and go to

https://us.battle.net/account/management/

(eu or us shouldn't matter)

Click on Diablo II, you'll be taken to the page with the key(screenshot is in Italian, but that shouldn't be a problem):

[image: Diablo key]

Comment: Everybody bow to my 1337 MSPaint skillz !!1!

Comment: Check for the screenshot, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Is that Italian? :D

Comment: @JamesJiao Yup, what does it look like to you?

Answer (score 10):

The key you want can be found under the details for that game in your account info on the battle.net website.

battle.net -> log in -> ACCOUNT (at the top) -> Diablo II

The `GAME KEY` will be visible on this page, as well as links to download the game.